# SCOM 2012R2 Installation Error

Tags: scom

I'm installing OPSMGR I have 2 x servers running WS2012R2 with Windows updates applied

SQL 2012 SP1 I've made sure the SQL collation is correct

I'm installing all roles apart from Reporting on the SCOM server. All of the Prerequisites have passed.

I can see the database is created in SQL but it doesn't go past "Operational Database Configuration"
It hangs on "Importing System Library Management Pack"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you installed IIS after .NET 4.0 it will not register properly with IIS. If this happens it will hang your install during the System Management MP import and you will need to re-register .NET 4.0 with IIS by running the following command (open command prompt and select run as administrator):

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -r
```

Once it is successfully registered, you should be good to go!

Comment: Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.33440
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440) and changing IIS configuration to use this version of ASP.NET.

Comment: This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog, the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440) and changing IIS configuration to use this version of ASP.NET.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any step by step guides to do this

Comment: Unless this is as easy as it sounds and I just remove the feature and re-add it under server manager?

Comment: You can try to remove the feature in server manager, reboot and thereafter attempt to re-add it again as pointed out in error message. Do let us know if it works..

Comment: It didn't work it complained about not being able to find .net installed. So I've rebuilt the server again. This time I've installed IIS first and then .net so we'll see what happens. But don't think its going to work as .net 4.5 comes preinstalled with WS2012R2

Comment: Error: :ImportManagementPack: Error: Unable to load management pack D:\Setup\AMD64\..\..\ManagementPacks\System.Library.mp
[22:19:50]: Error: :: Database error. MPInfra_p_ManagementPackInstall failed with exception: 
Database error. MPInfra_p_ManagementPackInstall failed with exception: 
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.

[22:19:50]: Error: :ImportManagementPack: Unknown Error. System.ArgumentException : The requested management pack is not valid.

Answer (score -1):

I installed SQL CU9 and it fixed my problem